# I want to track how many times a person has waved to me. What do I need to add then?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, calldata

Hi I am pretty new to coding and am sometimes getting confused in how to do certain things.

In my code, I want to track how many times a person has waved to me. What do I need to add then?

here is my code :

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract WavePortal { 

    uint256 totalWaves; 
    uint totalWavesPerPerson;

    constructor() {
        console.log("Yo yo, I am a contract and I am smart");
    } 

    function wave() public { 
        totalWaves += 1;
        console.log("%s has waved!", msg.sender);
    } 


    function getTotalWaves() public view returns (uint256){ 
        console.log("We have %d total waves ", totalWaves);
        return totalWaves; 
    } 
}
```

```
const main = async () => {
  const [owner, randomPerson] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();
  const waveContractFactory = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("WavePortal");
  const waveContract = await waveContractFactory.deploy();
  await waveContract.deployed();

//  console.log("Contract deployed to:", waveContract.address);
//  console.log("Contract deployed by:", owner.address);

  // Stored data
  let waveCount;
  waveCount = await waveContract.getTotalWaves();

  let waveTxn = await waveContract.wave();
  await waveTxn.wait();

  


// The waves
  waveCount = await waveContract.getTotalWaves();

  waveTxn = await waveContract.connect(randomPerson).wave();
  await waveTxn.wait();

  waveCount = await waveContract.getTotalWaves();





};

const runMain = async () => {
  try {
    await main();
    process.exit(0); // exit Node process without error
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    process.exit(1); // exit Node process while indicating 'Uncaught Fatal Exception' error
  }
};

runMain();
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly you could use a mapping to do it by mapping the waver's address to a count of their waves. increment the count each time the user waves.

solidity

```
mapping (address => uint) public numOfWaves;


function wave() public { 
    totalWaves += 1;
    console.log("%s has waved!", msg.sender);
    ++numOfWaves[msg.sender];

}
```

---

javascript

```
const waverAddress = <Wayne's address>
numOfWaves = await waveContract.numOfWaves(waverAddress)
console.log("Wayne waved %d times", numOfWaves)

waverAddress = <Wendy's address>
numOfWaves = await waveContract.numOfWaves(waverAddress)
console.log("Wendy waved %d times", numOfWaves)
```